# sencha touch 2.3 with phonegap only default icons / splash

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I'm running Sencha Touch 2.3 with Sencha Cmd v4.0.0.203. Phonegap 3.1.0-0.15.0.
the integration is running fine but my problem is that my icons / splash will not be used. i have defined it in config.xml eg. for icon

```
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="resources/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="resources/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="resources/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="resources/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
```

i'm running sencha app build native, the build process passed and the app is working on device but with default phonegap icons and splash. the icons will be copied to www/resources but in platform/ios/APP/Resources and platform/android/res the default icons are still existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using sencha command to build the application. You will have to manually place the icons under the platform/android/res folder. There is a bug in the phonegap-cli to get this working in local build.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/58

Comment: i copied it manually first time and if i change or add an new icon i copy it manually. the fixes resolved it in cordova 3.0.0 but i use phonegap 3.1 so if i have no error in reasoning it should already work

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was having the same issue, but with phonegap build.

If you have hydration enabled ( in phonegap build ), try disabling it. Rebuild all packages if it doesn't do it automatically.

It seems that with hydration enabled, it may not be doing a full rebuild everytime.

Once you get your icons and splash screens straightened out, you should be able to re-enable hydration.